# Can we take any decision about the quadrants, through which a line-segment passes, from its slope?

Tags: geometry

Can we take any decision about the quadrants, through which a line-segment passes, from the value and sign of the slope of a line-segment?

For instance, can we tell that since the slope is between 0 and 1, the line-segment must be passing through 2nd and 4th quadrant and so on?

What other information can we extract from the magnitude and sign of a slope?

I have generated this data.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-B-1BTjmHpwY0diUS1ZLUF4MFU/preview

From this I found that:

- There is no difference between slopes of lines and line-segments.
- If the sign is negative, it passes through 2nd and 4th quadrant.
- If the sign is positive, it passes through 1st and 3rd quadrant.
- If $0<m<1$, the line passes through $0 ^{\circ}$ to $45^{\circ}$ or $181^{\circ}$ to $225^{\circ}$.
- If $m>1$, the line passes through $46 ^{\circ}$ to $90^{\circ}$ or $226^{\circ}$ to $270^{\circ}$.
- If $m<0$, the line passes through $91 ^{\circ}$ to $180^{\circ}$ or $271^{\circ}$ to $360^{\circ}$.
- If $m>0$, the y value is increasing.
- If $m<0$, the y value is decreasing.

Comment: That's harder. There are many segments with  the same slope, so the answer can't be only in function of the slope.

Comment: A line _segment_ can be so short as to lie entirely in any quadrant regardless of its angle - imagine four separate line segments of length one with $(\pm 100, \pm 100)$ as their centers; then obviously the slope has no bearing on the quadrant.

Comment: OTOH, if you're interested in a (doubly-infinite) line, then  any line of positive slope will have portions in the first and third quadrants, and any line of negative slope will have portions in the second and fourth, and this isn't hard to see. (Lines of zero or infinite slope are rather special-casey.)

Comment: @anonymous you ought to add that the y-cut is 0.

Comment: Examining your data, you seem to have about a 0.1% error in all your calculations. This is how you get a slope of only 3374.65 at a 90-degree angle; a line truly at 90 degrees has an undefined slope, and a computer program with an ordinary level of accuracy for such problems should give you either "infinite" slope or at least an extremely large slope at that angle.

Comment: @davidk how can I reduce computation error.

Comment: Use more accurate numbers, or use better software. All I can tell from the printout is that it appears to be computer-generated and inaccurate; I see no indication how you created it or even what software you used.

Comment: I just used a c++ program.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean the y-cut is $0$. In other words, the equation of the line is of the form $$y=mx$$ where there is no constant term. I will also only consider lines and not line segments, as it is obvious that a line segment could be defined in such a way that it only falls in one quadrant (See [Steven Stadnicki's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405024/can-we-take-any-decision-about-the-quadrants-through-which-a-line-segment-passe#comment2862242_1405024)). Then, I agree with your list of properties, except for the following amendments:

- If $0<m<1$, the line lies at an angle of between $0 ^{\circ}$ and $45^{\circ}$ or between $180^{\circ}$ to $225^{\circ}$ to the horizontal.
- If $m>1$, the line lies at an angle of between $45 ^{\circ}$ and $90^{\circ}$ or between $225^{\circ}$ and $270^{\circ}$ to the horizontal.
- If $m<0$, the line lies at an angle of between $90 ^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$ or between $270^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$ to the horizontal.

Comment: What does it mean by "to the horizontal"?

Comment: the angle between a horizontal line and the line in question

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, can we tell that since the slope is between 0 and 1, the line-segment must be passing through 2nd and 4th quadrant and so on?

$$y=0.5x+1$$

does not go through 4th quadrant.

$$y=0.5x-1$$

does not go through 2nd quadrant.

$$y=0.5x$$

does neither go through 2nd nor 4th quadrant.